# How can I call parent's parent class method withouting calling parent's method when using chaining inheritance?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer class looks like this:

```
class BargainOrdersAdminSerializer(BargainOrdersSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if validated_data.get('logistics_company') and validated_data.get('logistics_tracking_no'):
            validated_data.update(is_shipped=True)
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)  # here, it will also call `BargainOrdersSerializer`'s update method which is not I am expected.
```

As you can see, it inherits from another serializer class as below:

```
class BargainOrdersSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ......
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        order = instance.order
        order.status = 'W'
        order.save(update_fields=['status'])
        wxpay_query.apply_async((order.id,),
                                countdown=60,
                                link_error=wxpay_error_handler.s(order.id))
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Which also override `update` method. And now, when I call `super().update(instance, validated_data)` in child class `BargainOrdersAdminSerializer`, it calls its parent class's overrided `update` also which is not I am expected. I want to ignore it. One approach I can figure out is like below. But I think it is a little weird. How can I handle it properly?

```
class BargainOrdersAdminSerializer(BargainOrdersSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if validated_data.get('logistics_company') and validated_data.get('logistics_tracking_no'):
            validated_data.update(is_shipped=True)
        #  I can implement my requirements in this way. But it looks like weird..
        return super(BargainOrdersSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: You could just call `BargainOrdersSerializer.update(self)` but if you have to do that your inheritance concept has failed.

Comment: Yeah. I did it as you said. Can I use multiple inheritance to handle it?